# Image of a morphism of sheaves of vector spaces is a sheaf: what are the restriction maps?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $f : \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$ be a morphism of sheaves of (complex) vector spaces on a space $X$, so $f$ is a collection of $f_U$ defined on open $U \subset X$.
The image of $f$ is defined in my lectures as as $$\mathcal{I}(U) := \{a \in \mathcal{G}(U) : \text{ there exists an open cover } U_i \text{ of } U \text{ s.t. } a\vert_{U_i} \in f(\mathcal{F}(U_i))\}.$$
I want to show that this is a sheaf, but I am struggling to work with the definition, even with defining what the restriction maps $\rho_{U,V}$ should do.
I have seen the fact that the category of sheaves of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces is abelian, and in Vakil's notes he says that

> We needn't worry about restriction maps - they "come along for the ride".

But when making things concrete, it is hard for me to resolve.
What am I misunderstanding here? I am fairly new to category theory and sheaves, so I would prefer something that uses as little of extra abstract machinery as possible.

Comment: The restriction maps simply come from $\matcal G$. Namely, $\rho_{U,V}=\mathcal G(i)$ where $i:U\to V$ is the unique arrow witnessing $U\subseteq V$.

Comment: The notation $\mathcal{G}(i)$ doesn't make sense, can you please clarify that?

Comment: Isn't $\mathcal G$ a contravariant functor from the poset of open subsets of $X$ to the category of vector spaces?

Comment: Ah you're right, I was stuck in my old notation of $\rho_{V,U}^\mathcal{G}$. The gluing property then is perfectly clear - thanks!